# Android Phone Verification using Self SMS

Tags: android, sms

I would like to verify the phone number by using an sms sent to the phone itself (Text or Data) and then compare the sent message with the received one.

The security flaw that I found is that, Android allows you to sniff the outgoing messages, and by doing so, you can easily get the sent message and repeat it to yourself leading to claiming that you own the phone number even if you do not.

The app does not have anyway to know that the received message is the one it sent or the repeated one.

Did anyone face the same problem before?

Comment: Do you want to verify the mobile number which is used in your phone?

Comment: Yes, I want whoever installs the app to verify the phone number currently used in the device.

Comment: Then the way you're trying to verify the phone number is flawed. You should have a server side implementation. The SMS will be generated and will be sent to the mobile from your server and your app will be detecting the incoming SMS which is coming from your server with an OTP. Then the app needs to verify the OTP again with a server call. Thus you can implement the mobile number verification process. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Reas, I already know this approach, I want to avoid using any SMS provider, that is why I stated (Self Sms),

Comment: Self SMS won't serve your purpose I think.